# SQL-Alchemy aggregation with one-to-one relation

Tags: python, angularjs, rest, sqlalchemy, flask

In simple Flask REST api for angular app I've got following models:

```
class User(db.Model, ModelMixin):
  """ attributes with _  are not exposed with public_view """
  __tablename__ = "users"
  id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
  username = db.Column(db.String(32), unique=True, index=True)
  _company_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey("companies.id"))

class Company(db.Model, ModelMixin):
  __tablename__ = "companies"
  id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
  name = db.Column(db.Unicode(32))
  _employees = db.relationship("User", backref="company", lazy="dynamic")
  _deal = db.relationship("Deal", backref="company", uselist=False)

class Deal(db.Model, ModelMixin):
  __tablename__ = "deals"
  id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
  active = db.Column(db.Boolean(), default=True)
  _company_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey("companies.id"))
```

Deal and Company have one to one relationship and Company and Users are one-to-many. I'm trying to define basic CRUD operations and return in this format:

```
deals = [
        {
         "id": 1,
         "comment": 'This is comment content',
         "company": {
           "id": 5,
           "name": 'Foo',
           "created_on": '20 Mar 2013',
         },
         "employees": [{
           "id": 7,
           "first_name": 'a',
           "last_name": 'b',
           "email": 'ab@b.com'
         },
         {
           "id": 8,
           "first_name": 'A',
           "last_name": 'B',
           "email": 'A@ghgg.com'
         }]
       },
       {
         "id": 2,
     ....
```

Right now I'm thinking of getting all active deals `Deal.query.filter_by(active = True).all()`  convert to dict, add company and query employees and add it, then return json.

**Is there a better way of generating?** With this solution I need to make n queries per n deals and I don't know how to do in SQL-Alchemy

Comment: If there are multiple deals with the same company are you sure you want to return the company and employee data for each one of them?  Would an alternate wire format be acceptable?

Comment: You are right I should not return employees here. I think I should just return the list of deals. Open to alt solution.

Comment: I am working on [Flask-Presst](https://github.com/biosustain/flask-presst), a REST API library designed explicitly for these kinds of scenarios (SQLAlchemy + embedding). It is a work in progress, but perhaps you will find it useful. I also recently added [Angular-Presst](https://github.com/biosustain/angular-presst), a matching AngularJS library to GitHub. (Also a work in progress)

Answer (score 2):

First, please read [Format of requests and responses](https://flask-restless.readthedocs.org/en/latest/requestformat.html) documentation. The format of the response of `flask-restless` is different from what you desire.

If you were to use `flask-restless`, currently it is not possible to preload `Deal._company._employees` (only level 1 relationships can be loaded). In your case you could register endpoint at `Company` though, which will load both `Company._deal` as well as `Company._employees`:

```
api_manager.create_api(
        Company, collection_name="custom_company",
        results_per_page = -1, # disable pagination completely
   )
```

then, doing:

```
rv = c.get('/api/custom_company_api',
        headers={'content-type': 'application/json'},
        )
```

will return something like:

```
{
  "num_results": XXX,
  "objects": [
    {
      "_deal": {
        "_company_id": 1,
        "active": true,
        "id": 1
      },
      "employees": [
        {
          "_company_id": 1,
          "id": 1,
          "username": "User1"
        },
        {
          "_company_id": 1,
          "id": 2,
          "username": "User2"
        }
      ],
      "id": 1,
      "name": "Company1"
    },
    {
...
}
```

I believe, this is all you can with flask-restless at this point. In case you were to provide your own custom endpoint, then you can get all the data in one `SQL` statement and convert to your desired format on your own. sqlalchemy query might look like this:

```
from sqlalchemy.orm import joinedload
qry = (db.session.query(Deal)
        .options(
            joinedload(Deal.company).
            joinedload(Company.employees)
            )
        .filter(Deal.active == True)
        )
```

*Note, however, that this will only work if your `_employees` relationship is not `"lazy='dynamic'"`*